# Issue configuring grunt to run babel

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, babeljs

I have a Gruntfile configured to, among other things, transpile an Express app to ES5 using Babel.

This is the configuration I have:

```
babel: {
    es6: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['server/**/*.{js,json}'],
                dest: 'output/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

This works pretty well. Most of my files are transpiled. The one issue that I run into is that the way my app is structured, the files aren't necessarily ending with just the .js extension. For example, I have in my transaction folder:

```
index.js
transaction.model.js
transaction.controller.js
transaction.model.spec.js
```

Therefore, in a hail mary I added the following to my configuration, to no avail.

```
babel: {
    es6: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['server/**/*.{controller,model,transaction,js,json}'],
                dest: 'output/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

How can I transpile these files with these 'custom' extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
babel: {
    es6: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['server/**/*.js'], 
                dest: 'output/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

or if for some reason it does not work try this

```
babel: {
    es6: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['server/**/*.controller.js'], // just add the ext plus the .js
                dest: 'output/',
                ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```